# $f_n$ sequence of integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${f_n} $be a sequence of integrable functions defined on an interval [a,b] .Then

1. If $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ a.e. then $\int _a^ b f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$.
2. $\int _a^ b f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ then $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$
3. If $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ a.e. and each $f_n $is a bounded function then $\int _a^ b f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$.
4. If$f_n(x)\rightarrow 0 $ a.e. and the f_n's are uniformly bounded ,then $\int _a^ b f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$

It can have multiple options right. Please give some hints. Also mention some reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}n, &x\in [0,\frac 1n]\\0, &x\in (\frac 1n,1]\end{cases} $$
2. Try $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}1, &x\in [0,\frac 1n]\\0, &x\in (\frac 1n,1]\end{cases} $$
3. Try as in 1.

[Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836483/f-n-sequence-of-integrable-function/836506#836506)

Comment: Even more simply in (2), take each $f_n(x)$ to be $1$ on the left half of $[a, b]$ and $-1$ on the right.

Comment: Even more simply than that: 1 at one point, 0 everywhere else.

Comment: Then we conclude that 4 is only true here. Have you mentioned any reference, the link is not there. Thanks for your answer.